# How to indent text like in a table, but without a table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

So basically the effect I want to achieve is something like the following:

```
          Wrapped Text Wrapped
 Text     Text Wrapped Text
          Wrapped Text
```

As if they were in two separate tds, in which case the code would have been like follows:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Text</td>
<td style="width: 150px;">Wrapped Text Wrapped Text Wrapped Text Wrapped Text</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But I want to accomplish this effect without tables, but by using HTML & CSS. How is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the text blocks in divs and float them:

HTML:

```
 <div id="div1">
    Text
 </div>


 <div id="div2">
       Text Wrapped Text
      Wrapped Text
         Wrapped Text Wrapped
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 #div1, #div2{float:left;width:100px}
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/GyMbS/

... but this leaves you with the challenge to vertically-center the either cell, as Amberlamps notes. That solution is tricky, and will depend on requirements of your text -- will it always be one-line? Will the height of the cells be fixed? See [Vertical Centering With CSS](http://www.vertical-align.com/) for solutions in various contexts.

**UPDATE - ALTERNATIVE**
Or you can use `display:table-cell` on the divs, which makes vertically aligning the left-cell much simpler:

```
#div1, #div2{display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;width:100px;}​
```

See this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/GyMbS/1/

**Major Caveat**: requires IE8 + or non-IE browser (see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)

Comment: That will not align the div1´s content vertically!